# Creating a user with email and password(both at the same time) Firebase Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I need to store the phone number, email, and name of the user.
Sign up screen has 4 `TextFields` 1.Mobile, 2.Email, 3.Name, 4.Password
I can create an account with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, but I've no idea about storing the phone number of a user. Do I need to set up phone verification? if so how can I store the email of the user and how to set up a phoneVerification method.

**Simply question is how to store the email, and phone number of a user at the same time**

Answer (score 1):

first signup the user with email and password; 
after signing up with email and also signing in use `FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber` method to start the phone verification process;

see this medium post : [Firebase phone auth with flutter(latest update)](https://medium.com/@fayaz07/firebase-phone-auth-with-flutter-db7e934ef46f);
also, read the comments in the dart file where the method `verifyPhoneNumber` exists;